# Do I need to request certificate for each my Apps to publish on App store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I just upload my app to app store and I have followed all instruction to request certificate then app id the provision profile.

I have a few apps and I would like to ask that do I need to request certificate for each apps?

Answer (score 1):

You only need one certificate that you use for each provisionning profiles.